# Navigation drawer crash after adding Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, menu, navigation-drawer

Hi I have problem with Navigation drawer. I used the default layout with navigation drawer to learn how to add more. I create similar classes like this default. But these thre clases witch was at the start are working, but another witch I crated don't and when i trying click into this three "naprawa", "oc", "pt" app is crashing.In every `fragment....xml` i have   `tools:context=".ui.<folder>.<...Fragment>"`with name of Fragments. Someone know where could be problem?
Also I have this errors:

```
    Process: com.example.carplanner, PID: 23240
    kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property naprawaViewModel has not been initialized
        at com.example.carplanner.ui.naprawa.NaprawaFragment.onCreateView(NaprawaFragment.kt:23)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

and this is the code :

```
package com.example.carplanner

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import android.view.View
import android.content.Intent


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }
        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(

            R.id.nav_home,
            R.id.nav_paliwo,
            R.id.nav_naprawa,
            R.id.nav_wydatki,
            R.id.nav_oc,
            R.id.nav_pt), drawerLayout)

        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)


            return true

    }


    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val id = item.itemId
        if (id == R.id.btn_settings) {
            val intent = Intent(
                    this, SettingsActivity ::class.java)
            startActivity (intent)
        }else{
            if (id == R.id.btn_about){
                val intent = Intent(
                    this, About ::class.java)
                startActivity (intent)
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
    }
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_dialer"
            android:title="@string/strona_g_wna" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_paliwo"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_paliwo"
            android:title="@string/tankowanie" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_naprawa"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_naprawa"
            android:title="@string/naprawy" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_wydatki"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_wydatki"
            android:title="@string/wydatki" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_oc"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_oc"
            android:title="@string/ubezpieczenia" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_pt"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/stat_notify_error"
            android:title="@string/przegl_d_techniczny" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="com.example.carplanner.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="Strona Główna"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_paliwo"
        android:name="com.example.carplanner.ui.paliwo.PaliwoFragment"
        android:label="Paliwo"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_paliwo" />


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_naprawa"
        android:name="com.example.carplanner.ui.naprawa.NaprawaFragment"
        android:label="Naprawy"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_naprawa" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_wydatki"
        android:name="com.example.carplanner.ui.wydatki.WydatkiFragment"
        android:label="Wydatki"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_wydatki" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_oc"
        android:name="com.example.carplanner.ui.oc.OcFragment"
        android:label="Ubezpieczenia"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_oc" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_pt"
        android:name="com.example.carplanner.ui.pt.PtFragment"
        android:label="Przegląd techniczny"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_pt" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_setting"
        android:name="com.example.carplanner.SettingsActivity$SettingsFragment"

        tools:layout="@layout/settings_activity" />

</navigation>
```

and the NaprawaFragment code:

```
package com.example.carplanner.ui.naprawa
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.example.carplanner.R


class NaprawaFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var naprawaViewModel: NaprawaViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        naprawaViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(naprawaViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_naprawa, container, false)
        val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_naprawa)
        naprawaViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            textView.text = it
        })
        return root
    }
}
```

And HomeFragment which is working properly

```
package com.example.carplanner.ui.home

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.example.carplanner.R

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        homeViewModel =
                ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home)
        homeViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            textView.text = it
        })
        return root
    }
}
```

Comment: add `NaprawaFragment` code

Comment: Ok, I added NaprawaFragment

Comment: It should be `NaprawaViewModel::class.java` instead of `naprawaViewModel::class.java`: `.get(NaprawaViewModel::class.java)`

Comment: I added HomeFragment which is working properly and it is look very similar

Comment: Yes exacly this was a problem, thanks a lot!